# Snaps can not launch on Ubuntu 18:04

Tags: 18.04, snap, atom, visual-studio-code

I am just 5 days old into this whole Ubuntu experience, after installing Ubuntu 18:04 everything was okay until just yesterday. I can not launch some snaps like Atom and VS Code.
When i launch them, i am redirected to the login screen. I have tried almost all the solutions on google including uninstalling them and reinstalling them, `$ sudo snap refresh`among other5. Any idea on what i can do ?

Comment: Did you purge and reinstall `snapd`? Is there anything interesting in `/var/log/syslog` after you launch a snap?

Comment: @Jos purging and reinstalling snapd didnot work